# How can I format messages with Perl's Mail::Outlook?

Tags: perl, ole, outlook-object-model

I'd like to format messages that I send using the Mail::Outlook.For e.g. change the font size or make it bold etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the `'message'` member of a Mail::Outlook::Message is just a [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176688%28v=office.12%29.aspx) object. If you want to *reach in*, you could just manipulate it. From the doc I'm looking at, you would set the `BodyFormat` and `HTMLBody` properties.

So say that `$outlook` is your `Mail::Outlook` instance. It *might* work to do this:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';

$message   = $outlook->create();
$mail_item = $message->{message};
$mail_item->{BodyFormat} = olFormatHTML
$mail_item->{HTMLBody}   = <<END_HTML;  
<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2>
<BODY>Type <b>something bold</b> here. </BODY>
</HTML>
END_HTML
```